# SQL statement to list final course grade for students taking two specific courses

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is my statement for the final course grade for all those students taking MATH, how can I adjust this so it displays the final course grade for MATH, but only for students who are taking both MATH and ART ?

```
SELECT sum(mark.mark * assignment.weighting/100)
FROM mark, assignment
WHERE (assignment.course = 'MATH') and (assignment.course = mark.course) and (assignment.assignnum = mark.assignnum)
group by mark.studnum
```

Comment: It would be easier for you to help if you entered sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT m.studnum, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.course = 'MATH' THEN m.mark * a.weighting / 100 END) final_course_grade
FROM mark m INNER JOIN assignment a
ON a.course = m.course AND a.assignnum = m.assignnum
WHERE m.course IN ('MATH', 'ART')
GROUP BY m.studnum
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.course) = 2
```

First, you should use a proper join with an `ON` clause and not that archaic syntax with the `,` between the table names and the join conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

For your requirement you must remove the condition `assignment.course = 'MATH'` from the `WHERE` clause because you want to check that the students took `'ART'` also.
This is done in the `HAVING` clause.

Also, note that if both `mark` and `weighting` are integers, then in this expression:

```
m.mark * a.weighting / 100
```

the division will truncate any decimal part because SQLite performs integer division between integers.
So, if you want a result with decimal part you should divide by `100.0`:

```
m.mark * a.weighting / 100.0
```

Comment: I was a little confused because I do not know the structure of the tables and sample data, but you are absolutely right. I will delete my answer